# JFileChooser browsing a remote file system

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am trying to Implement a JFileChooser that allows a user to select files on a remote system via ftp.

Everything I've read says this can be accomplished by extending FileSystemView so that all the file system methods (getFiles, etc) are overridden and routed across ftp.

I haven't had any luck implementing this, as FileSystemView appears to still be calling local functions.

Can anyone confirm that this can be done and/or point me in a good direction?

Comment: I don't follow. If you override all the methods in `FileSystemView`, it wont get a chance to call anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [vfsjfilechooser](http://vfsjfilechooser.sf.net)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your own FileSystemView and prevent access to the local file systems, you must of course override all methods or at least getSystemDisplayName and all the is* methods. Another problem is of course that the FileSystemView interface is closely linked to the File class, so it may not be trivial to provide a non-file-based implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this could be done. For a starter you could check out how the author of [MediaChest (aka PhotoOrganizer)](http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/) has done it.

Discovered the relevant code files here [Codase: FtpFileSystemView](http://www.codase.com/search/display?file=L2dlbnRvbzIvdmFyL3RtcC9yZXBvcy9zb3VyY2Vmb3JnZS9tZWRpYWNoZXN0L01lZGlhQ2hlc3QtMTM1X3ppcC9NZWRpYUNoZXN0L3NyYy9waG90b29yZ2FuaXplci9mdHAvRnRwRmlsZVN5c3RlbVZpZXcuamF2YQ==&lang=java&wds=swing+filechooser+filesystemview+)