# JFileChooser to browse Remote Linux machine's folders - Example

Tags: java, linux, swing, remote-access, jfilechooser

I am working on a Java Swing window Desktop application, which will have to browser the networked linux machine's folder to get a license file path. Being new to JAVA SWING and such protocols can someone show me an example to achieve it.

Research Note:

1. JFileChooser cannot be used to connect to the networked machines.
2. There are several other lib like vfsjfilechooser to connect to
   remote machine.. but still I dont understand the where and how to
   pass linux machine url and path.
3. I have tried to use ftp but it need to be run as server application. Now it is running as JAVA APPLICATION.

Comment: *"JFileChooser cannot be used to connect to the networked machines"* - If Windows Explorer can see, so can `JFileChooser`

Comment: Does the linux machine have any samba shares?  If so, you should be able to use `\\{network machine name}\{share name}`.  If not, then `JFileChooser` is not the right choice for the job...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser browsing a remote file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732179/jfilechooser-browsing-a-remote-file-system)

Comment: @Sanjeev The mentions `vfsjfilechooser` in there post...

Comment: @MP: The specified Linux machine will not have any shared folders.

Comment: @sanjeev: Thanks for your suggestion, I have already checked that post. I need a example to connect to Linux machine.

Comment: I do not know why this question has to be closed so soon without a proper answer. My Question is very different from others. 
Here I have asked for fileChooser example to connect with remote linux machine. I have explored and coded a lot but still I am unable to achieve this feature with JAVA swing.